# Best way to distinguish two calling assemblies that refer to static property

Tags: c#, .net

Assembly "A" provides valuable class that provides static property...

```
class ValuableClass
{
  public static string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Assemblies "B" and "C" use ValuableClass and it's static property. Everyhing is ok until "B" and "C" are loaded in the same process.

How should I refactor MyStaticProperty implementation to keep "B" and "C" calls isolated? I can't rely on thread ID's (several threads may change static property for every assembly) and I also can't rely on Process ID, because it's the same process.

I guess simplified code should look like the following, but I'm not sure it's the best practice

```
protected static IDictionary<string, string> MyProperties
public static string MyProperty
{
  set {
     string key = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName
     MyProperties[key] = value;
  }
  get {
     string key = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName
     return MyProperties[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: What you saay is not totally true, is possible to have different static property in different threads: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sounds like you want an instance, and not a static property.

Comment: Static properties are not the correct mechanism here.  You'll have to roll-your-own to achieve this using static property.  An instance would be a good way as well.

Comment: @Dan-o that right but I'd preffer not refactor all client code because of it's poor test coverage.

Comment: @GeirGrusom that's true but I'd preffer not to refactor all client code because of it's poor test coverage.

Comment: @SalvatoreSorbello yes, I can, but it's not exactly I want to achieve. Several threads of the same assembly should work with static property normally. But calls from another assembly (may be even with the same threads) should be isolated.

Comment: You might be able to create a couple wrapper classes around your `ValuableClass` with the same semantics as your current `ValuableClass` and then modify `ValuableClass` to become non-static.  This is just a off-the-cuff idea.  It will take some real design work to flesh out.  It may not pan out at all.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a static property:

```
class ValuableClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now both `B` and `C` can create a separate *instance* of `ValuableClass`.

---

Now, how do we make those instances accessible to all of B and C? The "clean" way would be to use dependency injection throughout B and C, but this might not be doable for a large legacy project.

As a simple solution, `B` and `C` could make *their instance* of `ValuableClass` available through static properties:

```
class SomeClassInB
{
     private static readonly ValuableClass myValuableStuff = new ValuableClass();
     public static ValuableClass MyValuableStuff { get { return myValuableStuff; } }
}

// same for C
```

Since `SomeClassInB` and `SomeClassInC` are only accessible in `B` and `C`, respectively, there is no risk of one assembly "polluting" the other one's data.

Comment: It's a nice idea, but I'm afraid to change client code because of it's poor test coverage. I'd preffer to bring changes to the only assembly keeping client code without changes.

Answer (score 1):

In situations when it is OK to call the getter before calling a setter, relying on `FullName` of the calling assembly is a rather fragile approach, because your code starts to rely upon a "magic constant" that identifies assemblies `B` and `C`. If you require a set before get, your approach would be fine. I would go even further, and used `Assembly` itself as the key into the dictionary:

```
protected static IDictionary<Assembly,string> MyProperties =
    new Dictionary<Assembly,string>();
public static string MyProperty {
    set {
       MyProperties[Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()] = value;
    }
    get {
       return MyProperties[Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()];
    }
}
```

If you would like a more controlled solution, replace the property with a method that takes an identifier, say, a GUID. This would let assemblies `B` and `C` make their own identifiers upfront, and use them as needed to get and set `MyProperty`:

```
protected static IDictionary<Guid,string> MyProperties =
    new Dictionary<Guid,string>();
public static string GetMyProperty(Guid id) {
    return MyProperties[id];
}
public static void SetMyProperty(Guild id, string val) {
    MyProperties[id] = val;
}
```